# Storyboard and customs cells I dont want to be reused

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, reusability, cells

In my app I have a table view with 12 types of custom cells.
I designed each within the storyboard.
In general everything works fine - thanks to your tutorials :)
My problem is, that I have individual styles an additional data in each cell - therefore I don't want them to be reused.
How can I generate a individual custom cell from storyboard to provide it in the -

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath?`

Any suggestions? 
Thanks
Dominic

Added:

```
    newCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType]; 
    cell = newCell;
    [cell styleWithElement:element andResubItem:resubItem];
```

my problem is, I need another way to create a custom-styled cell from the storyboard than the quouted above - I have no XIB and the above way is the only way I know to create my cell.
Could it be a solution to create a celltype once the above way and then copy the cell? Is there a way to copy a cell-object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random cell ID each time so it won't be reused.

However, that would not be very good for scroll performance and memory consumption, so consider actually reusing the cells (i.e. come up with a way to replace data in them).

Edit:

you can always just copy the views from one to another, something along these lines:

```
UITableViewCell* myCell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:YOUR_CELL_STYLE reuseIdentifier:YOUR_RANDOM_ID];
for (UIView *view in newCell.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [myCell addSubview: view];
}
```

You may also need to adjust the frame of myCell to be the same as that of newCell, and if newCell is an action target for any events (e.g. clicking a control element within the cell triggers some action defined in the cell class) you'll need to reassign those to the myCell, too.

Edit2:

To move actions you could do something like this:

```
NSSet* targets = [control allTargets];
for(id target in targets) {

    NSArray* actions = [control actionsForTarget:target forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    for(NSString* selectorName in actions) {
    [newControl addTarget:target action:NSSelectorFromString(selName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

Substitute your new cell for the target - and make sure it implements all the necessary selectors (or you can put a new selector). The code above will replace targets for UIControlEventTouchUpInside - you can use the ones you need instead (or use allControlEvents to enumerate the ones used by a control).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But since I use storyboard I have to apply the cell identifer I used in the storyboard - or is it possible to create a new cell depending on a storyboard cell without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Comment: See the modified answer. BTW you may want to add a comment after editing your question - otherwise people who respond to you won't get a notification.

Comment: but which YOUR_CELL_STYLE should I submit? I have the cell designs in the storyboard and I can not adress them via initWithStyle, can I?

Comment: Probably any style would do - they are "presets" for the views that the cell would have, but you are adding your own views, so just set the UITableViewCellStyleDefault and remove all views from myCell before adding the new views. Note that various UITableViewCell properties - like textLabel, imageView, etc. won't work because they are wired to the default views and you will be throwing them away and replacing them with your own views.

Comment: my cell is own subclass, so I created my own subclass cell, associated it with the unique identifer and copyied all views as you suggested - works!!   ...till the first user action occurs, because I have attached gesturerecognizer at some cell.subviews... hmmm.... I think I have to go the way to save all relevant cell-properties (and esspecially the sub.object.properties) and restore them when the row is reappearing.... thank you @SVD for the exchange

Comment: Sure. I've added another example on how to move action targets from one control to another - you can run that on all controls in one cell while copying them to another one.